# sed: find and replace nth character in a line that starts with a specific string

Tags: sed, regexp-replace

I have a couple thousand files with the same line formatting. I am trying to replace the 17th character (a letter) in every line that begins with a string (the word "ATOM"), without changing anything else in the file. So for example, I'd like to replace the 17th character after the word ATOM from "D" to "A":

INPUT

> ATOM  14632 2HG2 VAL D 923      56.949  47.137  72.598  1.00  0.00           H

OUTPUT

> ATOM  14632 2HG2 VAL A 923      56.949  47.137  72.598  1.00  0.00           H

I'm using the following code, which changes the letter, but deletes everything before it in that line:

```
sed -i '.bak' 's/^\(ATOM.\{17\}\)D/\A/' input.file
```

OUTPUT

> A 923      56.949  47.137  72.598  1.00  0.00           H

Any help on what I'm doing wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

The '.bak' is there since I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Use `awk`. Like literally `awk '$1 == "ATOM" && $5 == "D" { $5 = "A" }` Does it have to be "17th character" and may be "5th field"? Aren't the fields separated in file by spaces?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. In this type of file each character is it's own column, so this letter would fall under column 22. Unfortunately though, there are more lines which have letters in this column that do not need replacement, hence the need to identify only lines with ATOM in them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's:

```
sed 's/^\(ATOM.\{16\}\)D/\1A/'
```

- `.\{16\}` - You said  `I'd like to replace the 17th character after the word ATOM from "D" to "A"`. So you want to match any **16 characters** and then match the 17th character that is a `D`.
- `\1` - put what is remembered with the first `\(...\)` there.
- `A` - followed by an `A`.

Comment: Thanks KamilCuk, that almost worked! Except I did need the 17...it didn't make the change with the 16 there. I also then used "." instead of 17 to just change every letter to "A".